# Overflow-x:hidden not working w/ Android (Samsung Epic) and possibly others

Tags: android, css, mobile, overflow, android-scrollbar

I'm using CSS media queries to adjust a site's layout based on the resolution/device. I've got the layout looking nice, but I can't make the horizontal scrollbar disappear. I've also tried eliminating the ability to zoom out to no avail... any advice would be appreciated. The site is dev.javelinexperiential.com.

Answer (score 2):

Know issue with all current versions of Android and iOS

See:

- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2118
- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2911