# Adding html to a page in jQuerymobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am very new to Jquerymobile,html5 and css.Now I am working on jquerymobile project in that i need to display the html code which i am getting from rest service in a page and i am doing by using the following code.

```
<div data-role="content" style="width:700px">
<div id="html_content">
</div>
</div>
```

and javascript is

```
$("#paystub-html").live('pageinit',function(){

$.getJSON(url,function(events){
$(events).each(function(i,item){

$(item.Data).appendTo($("#html_content"));

});
});

});
```

I can display the html but not fully its not scrolling horizontally.I tried by using overflow tag also but its not solved.

Is there any other way to do that one ? how ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try adding the attribute overflow-x="scroll" to you html_content div ?

Comment: then it is strange that is doesn't work. what happens if you simply put the static content in the div ? do you get the scrolling ? It is going to be difficult to help you without an example of what is added on your page

Comment: http://115.160.224.88:8083/MyOVSService.svc/Compensation/My/Paystub/2/7e8e3f08-20b6-441b-a717-b85fef9b3c09 this is the url i am using.

Comment: thanks, that makes it simpler

Answer (score 0):

This situation can be solved with `overflow`, but you will first need to remove the `width` from the content to have things handle properly

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="html_content" style="overflow-x:scroll">
    </div>
</div>
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hjLyr/)

By the way, jQuery mobile standard usage would require you to include your content in a page container.

Comment: I already tried this one .Its scrolling in desktop browser but not in android device browser and emulator browser.

Comment: Then yours is a significantly different question: how to get overflow-x:scroll to work on android devices. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909669/overflow-xhidden-not-working-w-android-samsung-epic-and-possibly-others) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591321/how-can-i-get-div-scroll-overflow-x-to-work-on-a-mobile-browser) can help.

Comment: Thanks bro for your effort.